# peformance increase from using PHC or HipHop for mysql queries?

Tags: php, performance, hiphop

I don't know too much about HipHop or PHC, but i do know that it compiles PHP code into more efficient C++ code, I also know, that most likely i do not need it, but, phpfog, a cloud based php app host, offers the option of using either or, so, my questions is, basically the only thing my php code consists of is mysqli prepared statements, there are a couple of other functions, but not much beyond that, but could i even use such a compiler, and would there be any performance increase?

Comment: If you want to improve performance in this case, it's probably better to look at the logical/physical structure of your database, and at the queries that you're executing. Use of EXPLAIN can help diagnose how the queries work on the MySQL server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HipHop and PHC are specific to PHP; they do nothing with MySQL stuff. So, no, they won't affect MySQL performance.

Comment: so, if i write some php basically just connecting to a database, and retrieving information, then printing the results, it won't have any effect?

Comment: It might have a very slight increase in speed on the PHP side of things but for MySQL it will still take the same time. Shame really :-(

Comment: Not a problem :-) It's why we're here on SO!

Answer (score 3):

Performance work is about measurement - measure performance, set goals, if you are not currently meeting them, then you profile your application in a non-production enviroment, on identical hardware.

It seems highly unlikely that using hiphop etc, would improve your query performance.

So decide

- How fast is fast enough
- Does your app currently meet this requirement?
- If not, measure where the slowness comes from

Often, databases appear slow because of latency, not the speed of queries. Measure everything, assume nothing.